# Curl crashes when running under cron

Tags: perl, http, ubuntu, curl, cron

I've got a really bizzare problem, I've googled this to death, and cannot for the life of me find an answer. I'm a bit of a newbie to programming (lt 2 years) so sorry if this is something obvious, or I've not provided adequate detail

The Problem is...
curl crashes when I call it for the 5th time in a while loop (when run from root's cron).
curl is fine when I run said while loop manually whilst logged in (about 50 iterations).

I run a bash script from cron
The bash script runs a perl script
The perl script calls curl within a while loop
On the 5th iteration of this while loop, curl is called and crashes (no output)

- I'm running cron as root (crontab -u root /path/to/the/crontab/file)
- I don't think it's environment based, as it runs fine 4 times
- If I end the while loop at 4 itterations and start it again, it still fails, so I figure the problem is not with the while loop.
- This exact script works fine on my old server running Ubuntu desktop ( I'm now on Ubuntu server 10.04)
- I think this a problem between curl and cron.

The line of the crash looks like this (vars filled in)

```
$err = system("/usr/bin/curl -f -v -s -r "36155357-36259993,36790101-37194555,53623979-53745261" http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2012040100/master/gfs.t00z.mastergrb2f21 -o /root/Desktop/getGFS_uploadGFS/GFS/windvect/gfs.t00z.mastergrb2f21.tmp");
```

I'm totally stumped write now, if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated. Below is the while loop (with the crash point highlighted near the bottom).

```
while ($fhr <= $hr1) {
   if ($fhr <= 9) { $fhr="0$fhr"; }
   $url = $URL;
   $url =~ s/\$FHR/$fhr/g;
   $url =~ s/\${FHR}/$fhr/g;
   $file = $url;
   $file =~ s/^.*\///;

   #
   # read the inventory
   #    $line[] = wgrib inventory,  $start[] = start of record (column two of $line[])
   #

   if ($windows eq 'yes') {
      $err = system("$curl -f -s $url$inv -o $OUTDIR/$file.tmp");
      $err = $err >> 8;
      if ($err) {
          print STDERR "error code=$err,  problem reading $url$inv\n";
         sleep(10);
         exit(8);
      }
  open (In, "$OUTDIR/$file.tmp");
   }
   else {
      open (In, "$curl -f -s $url$inv |");
   }

   $n=0;
   while (<In>) {
      chomp;
      $line[$n] = $_;
      s/^[^:]*://;
      s/:.*//;
      $start[$n] = $_;
      $n++;
   }
   close(In);
   if ($n == 0) {
       print STDERR "Problem reading file $url$inv\n";
       sleep(10);
       exit(8);
   }

   #
   # find end of record: $last[]
   #

   $lastnum = $start[$n-1];
   for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $num = $start[$i];
      if ($num < $lastnum) {
         $j = $i + 1;
         while ($start[$j] == $num) { $j++; }
         $last[$i] = $start[$j] - 1;
      }
      else {      
         $last[$i] = '';
      }
   }

   if ($action eq 'inv') {
      for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
         print "$line[$i]:range=$start[$i]-$last[$i]\n";
      }
      exit(0);
   }

   #
   # make the range field for Curl
   #

   $range = '';
   $lastfrom = '';
   $lastto = '-100';
   for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $_ = $line[$i];
      if (/$LEVS/i && /$VARS/i) {
         $from=$start[$i];
         $to=$last[$i];

         if ($lastto + 1 == $from) {
            $lastto = $to;
         }
         elsif ($lastto ne $to) {
            if ($lastfrom ne '') {
               if ($range eq '') { $range = "$lastfrom-$lastto"; }
               else { $range = "$range,$lastfrom-$lastto"; }
            }
            $lastfrom = $from;
            $lastto = $to;
        }
      }
   }
   if ($lastfrom ne '') {
      if ($range eq '') { $range="$lastfrom-$lastto"; }
      else { $range="$range,$lastfrom-$lastto"; }
   }


   if ($range ne '') {


    #################################################################################
    ########### THE BELOW LINE IS WHERE CURL IS CALLED AND IT CRASHES ###############
    #################################################################################


      $err = system("$curl -f -v -s -r \"$range\" $url$grb -o $OUTDIR/$file.tmp");
      $err = $err >> 8;
      if ($err != 0) {
         print STDERR "error in getting file $err $url$grb\n";
         sleep(20);
         exit $err;
      }
      rename "$OUTDIR/$file.tmp", "$OUTDIR/$file";
      $output = "$output $OUTDIR/$file";
   }
   else {
      print "no matches (no download) for $file\n";
   }
   $fhr += $dhr;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "crashes"? Is there a core dump? A message to stderr? If the latter, please post it exactly. If the former, installing debug symbols and collecting a stack trace would be useful.

Comment: One more thing: What's the return value of `system`?

Comment: OK, @CharlesDuffy you've solved the problem.  For some reason the crash was occurring on the 5th iteration when trying to write to stderr. 

When I redirected it by using `script.pl >> log00.log 2>&1` it began to work.

This still leaves lots of confusion as to why this is happening if it wasn't happening on the old server, and why it was happening after the 4th iteration.  @ikegami I'm not sure what the return value of system is, how would I get that?

My problem is solved, but I don't fully understand why

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to shell out to curl? If it's just the range, that's easy:

```
use v5.10.1;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

say Mojo::UserAgent->new->get(
    'http://www.example.com',
    { 'Range' => 'bytes=500-600' }
    )->res->body;
```

There are also Perl bindings to [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/): [Net::Curl](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aCurl) and [WWW::Curl](https://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aCurl).

Comment: Thanks for this tip, the shell script triggers multiple things (a few perl scripts written by the NOAA that use curl to download partial grib files.  A lot of other modular shell scripts are spawned from this script too).  The perl scripts that use curl were pre written by NOAA, I haven't had time to really investigate how they are written.

http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/get_gfs.html